# Object equals self or empty object

Tags: javascript

I've got a JavaScript that uses this notation to make sure an object is initialized:

```
MyObject = MyObject || {};
```

I understand what it does, namely checking wether MyObject is anything, if not assigning an empty object to `MyObject`. I don't really know all the internals of JS that well, so I don't see how a logic comparison could be used in an assignment.

How does it work? Is there any other languages that allows this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the language.

For example, in Ruby, you could use this style.

But in PHP, you could not use this style, because in PHP, the Logical Operators always returns a boolean value (true/false).

***Conclusion:***

If the Logical Operators always **return a boolean value**, then you could not use this style.

If the Logical Operators returns **the first value when first value evaluates true otherwise return the second value**, then you could use this style.

Comment: I guess it's the combination that JS interprets undefined values as false and that logical comparisons doesn't necessarily return a bool that does it. Thanks to you and Peter for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax means "assign `MyObject` to itself, if it's defined. Otherwise, give it the empty object."

It works because Javascript treats undefined values as false, and defined ones as true. Combine that with lazy evaluation of logical expressions, and you get the behavior described above.

Answer (score 1):

The logical-'or' operator has short-circuit semantics, which means that the right-hand operand is only evaluated if the left-hand one evaluates as `false`. Thus if `MyObject` *is* initialized, the statement reads `MyObject = MyObject;` (which does nothing), and otherwise it is `MyObject = {};`.